# The synchronous behavior of The Multi-Threaded Method

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview, arraylist

After a long work hours on this, i couldn't get any success with `multi-threading` with this method. i really appreciate your help.

i have a `listview` and in it first column has urls that we will need later in other methods. seconds column is for the result.

I'm creating two `ArrayLists` with urls and sending them(urls with arraylist) to the method, then in the method, with a `httpwebrequest`, i'm getting the page title from each url.

So the problem is when i try to fire `5 threads`, it works like :

(U : url, R: result)

u1 = r1 ( so, i must get u1's result as r1..)

but i'm getting like :

u1 = r1, u2 = r1, u3(or4) = r1, u4 = r1, u5=r2(or3,4)

but what i expecting :
u1=r1, u2=r2, u3=r3, u4=r4...

For better explanation please check **the pictures below**

then i tried to use `Lock` keyword with a private object but then i lost `multi-threading`.it works as i excepted but one by one. not fire 5 different threads at the same time and waits finishing the thread 1 for move to the next thread.

///Main Class///

```
/* A store of all created threads. */
ArrayList _threads = new ArrayList();
/* A store of all FileDownloader objects. */
ArrayList _instances = new ArrayList();
private int _activeDownloadCount = 0;
object _lockObject = new object();
```

The Button :

```
_instances = new ArrayList();
_threads = new ArrayList();
_activeDownloadCount = 0;

FileDownloader download = null;
foreach (ListViewItem item in listviewUrl.Items)
{               
  item.SubItems[9].Text = "Not started";        

    download = new FileDownloader(item.SubItems[0].Text);               
    item.Tag = download;                
    try
    {
       ThreadStart tsDelegate = new ThreadStart(download.Download);
       download.DownloadStarting += new FileDownloader._delDownloadStarting(download_DownloadStarting);
       download.DownloadCompleted += new FileDownloader._delDownloadCompleted(download_DownloadCompleted);

       Thread t = new Thread(tsDelegate);
       t.Name = item.SubItems[0].Text;
       _threads.Add(t);
       _instances.Add(download); 
    }
    catch
    {

        item.SubItems[9].Text = "Error";
    }
}
StartDownload();
```

StartDownload Method :

```
int j = 0;
int limit = int.Parse(numThreadSearch.Text);
int iCount = 0;
lock (_lockObject)
{
    iCount = _instances.Count;
}
if (iCount != 0)
{
    foreach (Thread thread in _threads)
    {
        FileDownloader file = ((FileDownloader)_instances[j]);
        if (file._IsStarted == false)
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                thread.Start();

                Console.WriteLine(_activeDownloadCount);
                _activeDownloadCount++;
            }
        }
        if (_activeDownloadCount == limit)
        {
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
else
{
    /* If all the files have downloaded, we will do something here.
}
```

when the method completed :

```
 void download_DownloadCompleted(FileDownloader thread, bool isSuccess)
        {

            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                _activeDownloadCount--;

            }

            PageRankReturns(FileDownloader._PageRankReturn, thread);
            RemoveFromInternalPool(thread);
            StartDownload();

        }


         delegate void delSetStatus(string Status, FileDownloader f);

     private void PageRankReturns(string Status, FileDownloader f)
            {
                if (listviewUrl.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    delSetStatus s = new delSetStatus(PageRankReturns);
                    this.Invoke(s, new object[] { Status, f });
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem item in listviewUrl.Items)
                    {
                        if (item.Tag == f)
                        {
                            /* Use locking to synchronise across mutilple thread calls. */
                            lock (_lockObject)
                            {
                                item.SubItems[2].Text = Status;

                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



 private void RemoveFromInternalPool(FileDownloader thread)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (FileDownloader f in _instances)
            {
                if (f == thread)
                {
                    /* If the file has downloaded, remove it from our pool. */
                    lock (_lockObject)
                    {
                        _threads.Remove(_threads[i]);
                        _instances.Remove(f);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
```

/// Second Class ///

```
#region  Fields

private string _DocumentUrl = string.Empty;
private string _DirectoryPath = string.Empty;
public bool _IsDownloading = false;
public bool _IsDownloadSuccessful = false;

public bool _IsStarted = false;

#endregion

#region Delegates
public delegate void _delDownloadStarting(FileDownloader thread);
public delegate void _delDownloadCompleted(FileDownloader thread, bool isSuccess);
public delegate void _delDownloadCWorking(FileDownloader thread);

#endregion

#region Events
public event _delDownloadStarting DownloadStarting;
public event _delDownloadCompleted DownloadCompleted;

protected static readonly object locker = new object();
public static string pageTitleResult= string.Empty;

public static string _pageTitleResult
{
    get { return pageTitleResult; }
}

public FileDownloader(string documentUrl)
{
    _DocumentUrl = documentUrl;
}
```

//Download Method //

```
public void Download()
{
    _IsStarted = true;
    DownloadStarting(this);            
    _IsDownloading = true;
    _IsDownloadSuccessful = false;

    // with lock keyword it works one by one//
    //without lock or monitor.enter keyword then it works as i tried explain above u1 = r1, u2 = r1, ur3 = r1, u4=r3 etc...

    try
    {
        string pageHtml = getHtml(_DocumentUrl);
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        //html agibility works with returned string from gethtml...
      // string pageTitle = html agibility work result, it's string...
       pageTitleResult = pageTitle 

        _IsDownloadSuccessful = true;
        _IsDownloading = false;
        /* raise a download completed event. */
        DownloadCompleted(this, _IsDownloadSuccessful);
    }
    catch
    {
        _IsDownloadSuccessful = false;
    }
   Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Lock Object :

```
protected static readonly object locker = new object();
```

Well, I just made an example in excel to show how it works...

This is the return without Lock keyword :
[image: Without Lock keyword for method]

This is with lock keyword, by the way, in this example, fired 5 threads but it waits first one's end...
[image]

and this is what I'm trying to do...
[image]

Comment: "pageTitleResult = pageTitle;" - What is a "pageTitleResult", "pageTitle "? Where are definition of them and where them are used?

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev i just edited this part.. it's just html agibility pack work and with it or without it the thread problem doesn't change, that's why i removed this part to clear code little bit.

Comment: I can't find in your code, where you insert strings into ListView columns: item.Subitems[1], where are the url, and item.Subitems[2], where are the result, if I are properly understand your post.

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev thank you for your time alexander, i just added other necessary methods that i used for multi threading.

Comment: In method PageRankReturns(), try "if (f.Equals(item.Tag))" instead of "if (item.Tag == f)".

Answer (score 0):

I think, a problem is in this method:

```
private void PageRankReturns(string Status, FileDownloader f)
{
            if (listviewUrl.InvokeRequired)
            {
                delSetStatus s = new delSetStatus(PageRankReturns);
                this.Invoke(s, new object[] { Status, f });
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listviewUrl.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Tag == f)
                    {
                        /* Use locking to synchronise across mutilple thread calls. */
                        lock (_lockObject)
                        {
                            item.SubItems[2].Text = Status;

                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

You must change a structure of your application. 
See a your method above ("PageRankReturns"). You run a cycle over all items of listview, to find a item for  FileDownloader. Why FileDownloader did know nothing about his item? If FileDownloader will know about his item, then you will not need of this cycle. And you will have a explicit link between FileDownloader and his Item.

Comment: the result is same. i think it's better to check all code. from here :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14219/Multi-threaded-file-download-manager . for the changes that i made you can see from above.

Comment: well, i think i will continue with parallel, i still couldn't solve the problem. @alexanderkiselev