# Parallel.ForEach and DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm having an issue converting .`AsParallel` to the `Parallel.ForEach`.
I have a `DataGridView` and i'm putting some values in the first column of it after that with `ForEach` loop i'm sending the value to method and getting a return value then i'm putting the return value to second column.

At the beginning; i was using `ForEach` loop but it takes too much time, then i decided to use .`AsParallel` but i think, in my situation, it might be better to use `Parallel.ForEach` but i couldn't make it work with `datagridviewrow`.

ForEach Method :

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dataGrid1.Rows)
 {
     // SOME CODES REMOVED FOR CLARITY
     string data1 = row.Cells[1].Value;
     var returnData = getHtml(data1);
     row.Cells[2].Value = returnData;
 }
```

AsParallel Method :

```
dataGrid1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().AsParallel().ForAll(row =>
{
    // SOME CODES REMOVED FOR CLARITY
    string data1 = row.Cells[1].Value;
    var returnData = getHtml(data1);
    row.Cells[2].Value = returnData;
});
```

So, how can i use `Parallel.ForEach` loop with `DataGridViewRow` (DataGridView) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally when working with UI components you need to interact with them on the main thread. You will notice that sometimes there won't be any issues interacting with it on multiple threads, but it can appear to be "buggy". You really should be working against a datasource that supports multithreading rather than interacting with the grid rows directly.

Comment: What is the bottleneck here: getting/settings cell values or executing getHtml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `getHtml` (and other non-UI part of your loop) is relatively expensive, then it makes sense to do what you are trying to do in parallel, if it is cheap then it does not make sense to do it in parallel because updating the UI (your data grid) needs to be sequential anyway since only the UI thread can update it.

If the `getHtml` (and other non-UI part of your loop) is relatively expensive, you can do the following:

```
var current_synchronization_context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => //This is important to make sure that the UI thread can return immediately and then be able to process UI update requests
{
    Parallel.ForEach(dataGrid1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>(), row =>
    {
        // SOME CODES REMOVED FOR CLARITY
        string data1 = row.Cells[1].Value;
        var returnData = getHtml(data1); //expensive call

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => row.Cells[2].Value = returnData,
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            current_synchronization_context); //This will request a UI update on the UI thread and return immediately
    }); 
});
```

Creating a `Task` and using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` will work in a Windows Forms application and in WPF application.

If you don't want to schedule a Task for each UI update, you can call the BeginInvoke method directly (if this is a Windows Forms application) like this:

```
dataGrid1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    row.Cells[2].Value = returnData;
}));
```

My suggestion above will cause data to be rendered to the UI as it is being processed/generated.

If you don't care about this, and you are OK with processing all data first and then updating the UI, then you can do the following:

1) Collect all data from UI in the UI thread

2) Process that data via Parallel.ForEach and store the result in an array

3) Render the data to the UI from the UI thread

Comment: I suggest simplify the code: just return the results as an array and then iterate over it. The overhead of scheduling a Task for each row is too much.

Comment: How can we be sure about the order of the data in the array?

Comment: Instead of create a new `Task`, we can call `BeginInvoke` directly.

Comment: `string[] res = new string[dataGrid1.Rows.Count]; Parallel.For(0, res.Length, index => { ... }`

Comment: That works and it is a valid option. But maybe the user of the application would like to see the data rendered as it is being generated. If he doesn't then what you are suggesting is the way to go.

Comment: Make it simpler! You can easily avoid calling tons of costly `BeginInvoke` methods. And you cannot fire and forget here: after method finished execution, the table will continue updating.

Comment: Negative. I assumed in the beginning of my answer that the cost of non-UI work (e.g. `getHtml`) is relatively expensive. This means that the UI thread is relaxed because it is not getting enough requests per second to be busy.

Comment: Thank you @YacoubMassad and AndreyNasonov, i learned a lot of things from you. I think i should explain little bit more why i'm trying to use parallel.foreach..getHtml method is a simple httpwebrequest that returns page's code , then with HTML Agility Pack i'm working for gathering some datas from it. for now it gives me one return but i will add at least 6 request more for getHtml and from tests i saw if i add 5-6 (each one different) requests for getHtml i must wait 0.5> sec for each row and with EachFor loop it will take a lot of times.. that's why i'm trying to make it multi threading.

Comment: by the way, last 2 days i was working on multi-threading with listview. but i heard from a lot of people in chat section of stackoverflow saying that parallel.foreach with will fit for my request. i already opened a thread for this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866093/the-synchronous-behavior-of-the-multi-threaded-method

Comment: @Aura, you should measure the performance of the system. First, do a normal `foreach` without any parallelism and measure how much time it takes. Then try to do some parallelism and see if it will make you gain any benefit in terms of time.

Comment: @YacoubMassad thank you again for your advice. i already measured it.i have more than 150 urls and i need to see many variables of them. Like pagerank, title, backlink counts etc..this mini-program is a request from my boss that's why i'm trying to figure out this problem. well, actually what do you suggest if you have to work with 150 url, listview (or datagridview) and many httpwebrequest for each url? which way is better to make a multi-threading with this requests ? i think i will have to start to work from beginning . thank you again.

Comment: I cannot answer with this little amount of information. For example, how frequently do you need the data to be updated? Are you going to display data from all the 150 URLs into the same view? I suggest that you post another question with details about your problem.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time. the answers for you question by the way ; the data must update only once after finishing the thread for url(requests), 2- yes.i'm importing the url list from csv file and then i'm firing the loop with start button. it's a simple program really. one datagridview (before it was listview), 3 buttons ( start, import to dgv and clear button) that's all for the program. i'm afraid of getting many downvotes for this question here :)